# Ressource folder in project path not found

Tags: c#, visual-studio

this worked in an older csharp visual studio project.

```
        String appRoot = AppContext.BaseDirectory.ToString();
        String FONT = appRoot + "resources\\font\\FreeSans.ttf";
```

now app root points to a different path ...\projectname\bin\Debug\net5.0\
and the resources are not moved there after compile.

they are still in ..\projectname

How can I use my resources folder in a csharp visual studio 2019 project again ?

Comment: add the file to the project and set `copy always` in the `copy to the output Directory` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the property of that file:

[image]

then change  "Copy to Output Directory" in Copy always.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the hint but I only have Misc Options not the advanced